# Issue parsing Jquery XML

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to pull data from my XML sheet, this  is the first time i have done this fyi.

Here is my jQuery.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "desk.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(xml) {
                $(xml).find('desk').each(function(){
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var desknum = $(this).find('desk#').text();
                    var phonenum = $(this).find('phone#').text();
                    var emailinfo = $(this).find('email').text();
                    $('<div class="desks" id="desk_'+id+'"></div>').html().appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        $('<div class="desknum"></div>').html(desknum).appendTo('#desk_'+id);
                        $('<div class="phonenum"></div>').html(phonenum).appendTo('#desk_'+id);
                        $('<div class="emailinfo"></div>').html(emailinfo).appendTo('#desk_'+id);
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
 <location>
   <desk id="1">
      <desk#>Camaron</desk#>
   <computer#>COR9838L</computer#>
<phone#>111.111.1111</phone#>
<email#>camaron@yahoo.com</email#>
<picture></picture>
  </desk>
  <desk id="2">
   <desk#>Greg</desk#>
<computer#>COR9838L</computer#>
<phone#>111.111.1111</phone#>
<email>camaron@yahoo.com</email>
<picture></picture>
  </desk>
  <desk id="3">
<desk#>Cesar</desk#>
<computer#>COR9838L</computer#>
<phone#>111.111.1111</phone#>
<email#>camaron@yahoo.com</email#>
<picture></picture>
   </desk>
  <desk id="4">
   <desk#>Tracy</desk#>
<computer#>COR9838L</computer#>
<phone#>111.111.1111</phone#>
<email#>camaron@yahoo.com</email#>
<picture></picture>
  </desk>
</location>
```

I also setup a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/Re6Nv/

Not sure why its not working.

Also I want to instead of creating a div id, i want my xml data to load to a correct div id. Just to give you an idea of what my plan is, i am building a location based format each desk will have an id on a map, the xml should point to the location on the map and place the data correctly. This is a big project so any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is not working because http://www.designsbycamaron.net/desk.xml sends a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desk.xml returns a 500 Internal Server Error, also I suggest you use this code once your XML file is accessible.

```
$.get('http://www.designsbycamaron.net/desk.xml', function(data){

    $(data).find('desk').each(function(){

        var $desk = $(this); 
        var id = $desk.attr("id");
        var desknum = $desk.find('desk#').text();
        var phonenum = $desk.find('phone#').text();
        var emailinfo = $desk.find('email').text();

        var html = '<div class="desks" id="desk_' + id + '">';
        html += '<div class="desknum">' + desknum + '</div>';
        html += '<div class="phonenum">' + phonenum + '</div>'; 
        html += '<div class="emailinfo">' + emailinfo + '</div></div>'; 

        $('#page-wrap').append($(html));

    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Re6Nv/6/

Comment: Great that worked. So my last question is, how do i now load content into a specific div. Let me give you some further info. See how i have desk id= i want that to put the data where that id is on the html page. So on my html page it will say div id="1" then all this content will get loaded under div id="1" with a div container called info then everything gets loaded into div container rather than #page-wrap

Comment: Never mind i got it!!   $('#page-wrap #desk_'+ id +' .content').append($(html));